# Access limitation to files in website

Tags: asp.net, file, security, web-config

How can i put limitation in access different user? My website, according to different
user, each user can only access to it's own files and i don't want other users to be
able to download another user's files via it's link

Answer (score 0):

Store the files outside of the web root and give them a key (not the file name). Create a handler to serve up the files. When a request is made for a file, ensure that the requested file id is valid, and the current user has access to the requested file. If everything is ok, read the file contents and write them to the http response.

Comment: What exactly is that handler, and how can I make it?

Comment: And while receiving a request for a file download, how can I recognize it's sender?

Comment: I think you have some basics to read up on. Look into "asp.net membership provider" and "generic handlers" or ashx files.

Comment: I don't have enough time now, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @HosseinEshaghi Not securely.